# pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to set-up Basemap on for my python code and one of its requirements is pyproj. I have downloaded pyproj and base map from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap)

My Python version is 2.7.13

My pip command is upgrade to latest version.

Also setuptools is also upgraded to latest version using below command

```
 pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

My Linux OS is x86_64 found by command

```
 uname -m
```

Now when I run below command:

```
pip install basemap-1.2.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

or

```
pip install pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

I see this error:

```
basemap-1.2.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

and

```
pyproj-1.9.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I ran below command to find the supported wheels:

```
 python -c "from pip import pep425tags;print(wheel.pep425tags.get_supported())"
```

I got below output:

```
 [('cp27', 'cp27mu', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp27', 'none', 'linux_x86_64'), ('cp27', 'none', 'any'), ('cp2', 'none', 'any'), ('cp26', 'none', 'any'), ('cp25', 'none', 'any'), ('cp24', 'none', 'any'), ('cp23', 'none', 'any'), ('cp22', 'none', 'any'), ('cp21', 'none', 'any'), ('cp20', 'none', 'any'), ('py2', 'none', 'linux_x86_64'), ('py27', 'none', 'any'), ('py2', 'none', 'any'), ('py26', 'none', 'any'), ('py25', 'none', 'any'), ('py24', 'none', 'any'), ('py23', 'none', 'any'), ('py22', 'none', 'any'), ('py21', 'none', 'any'), ('py20', 'none', 'any')]
```

Can someone help me with my issue?

Comment: the wheels you are trying to install are for 64bit windows (`win_amd64` part). Judging by the PEP 425 tags you posted, you need wheels named `<pkg>-<ver>-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl` (beware that `cp27m` in wheel name won't work either! You need wheels for Python with wide unicode support).

Comment: Thanks! I have looked for linux version of this basemap file, and couldn't find anything. Can you help me with that?

Comment: `pyproj` is available on PyPI, so `pip install pyproj` will do. As for `basemap`, it is replaced by `cartopy` which can be also installed from PyPI: `pip install cartopy`. If you really need `basemap` (e.g. to support some legacy code), you can install `basemap` directly from github: `pip install --user git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've installed pyproj using `pip install pyproj`. But `pip install cartopy` is giving me an error: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-n71hEq/cartopy/`.

Comment: To add, I've installed all the dependencies required for cartopy. Except proj4. For proj4, I am getting `pip install PROJ4`
`Collecting PROJ4
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PROJ4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PROJ4`

Comment: Sure, you need both `proj` and `geos` libraries to be properly installed before you can install `cartopy`; refer to [installation instructions for details](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/installing.html). Both are no python packages, but C++ libs, so you are either lucky and your distro ships those as packages (and then you can be proud of yourself because of the wise choice of distro), or you will need to build both libs from source.

Comment: Example for Debian: `apt install libgeos proj-bin` or on my Gentoo box: `emerge sci-libs/geos sci-libs/proj`. If your distro doesn't have the packages, here are the instructions on how to build both libs from source: [for `geos`](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/wiki/BuildingOnUnixWithAutotools) and [for `proj`](https://proj4.org/install.html#compilation-and-installation-from-source-code). Basically, building both from source isn't that scary, download and unpack the source code and run the usual `configure && make && make install`. However, sticking to the manual is no shame either.